# Difference between ClassCastException and error at compile time while casting one class object to other type

Tags: java

```
class A 
class B extends A
class C extends B
Line 1- C c = new B();   //CTE: Type mismatch: cannot convert from B to C
Line 2- B b = (B) a;     //A type is explicitly down casted to B type.
Line 3- C c = (C) b;    //Here, you will get class cast exception but why 
                          not CTE?
```

My question is why Line 1 throws CTE instead of ClassCastException at run time like line 3? 
what happens behind the scene and how compiler comes to know that this is incorrect and it throws compile time error for line 1 and why compile can not understand that line 3 is also throwing error and it should be thrown at compile time only instead of ClassCastExcepion at run time.

I hope my question is clear and I checked many questions on here but none of them seemed to be given answer my question so please before marking duplicate make sure other question answers my questions.

Comment: Mainly because in line 1 you're not casting anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
class B extends A
class C extends B

Line 1- C c = new B()
```

That is like:

```
Dog doggy = new Mammal();
```

Which can't work. Every C is a B, but not every B is a C!

Your third line "3-" is (conceptually) like this:

```
Dog doggy = (Dog) new Mammal();
```

Which is also nonsensical, but well, that is the thing with casts. You tell the compiler "I know better than you". When you are right, great. When not, you get your fingers slapped at runtime.

In other words: casts are a way to "override" the compiler. Without them, the compiler tells you "this here isn't possible". With the cast, as said: "compiler, trust me, this is fine". Which, in your case, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Cince `C` extends `B`, Any `B` object can potentially be an upcasted `C`. Compiler can't always know that for sure, so it's only detected at runtime.